# Convert IP address to ulong in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, type-conversion, boost-asio

need to convert IP address to unsigned long using Python.
In C++ code I do this using

```
boost::asio::ip::address_v4::from_string("127.0.0.1").to_ulong()

Output: 2130706433
```

In Python so far I have been able to convert this to hex but not to ulong.

```
>>> socket.inet_aton('127.0.0.1')
'\x7f\x00\x00\x01'
```

Can you please help me with conversion of IP to ulong in Python?

Comment: `print(int(socket.inet_aton('127.0.0.1').replace('\x',''),16)) #2130706433`

Comment: Liked @chakri solution as this is short one. But this is not working in 2.7